# when flutter upgrade app shows errors msg

Tags: android, flutter

Yesterday I did a flutter upgrade and these messages started to appear in the Run panel below in Android Studio. The app works well and does not have any problems with the code .. The problem is the appearance of these messages while opening and browsing the application
How to solve the problem and remove these messages, thanks for help

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A105FN in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Syncing files to device SM A105FN...
D/ViewRootImpl@e295047[MainActivity]( 4054): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][720,1520] new=[0,0][720,1520] result=0x1 surface={false 0} changed=false
D/ViewRootImpl@e295047[MainActivity]( 4054): stopped(false) old=true
D/SurfaceView( 4054): windowStopped(false) false io.flutter.view.FlutterView{9a0a9e3 VFE...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} of ViewRootImpl@e295047[MainActivity]
D/SurfaceView( 4054): onWindowVisibilityChanged(0) true io.flutter.view.FlutterView{9a0a9e3 VFE...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} of ViewRootImpl@e295047[MainActivity]
D/ViewRootImpl@e295047[MainActivity]( 4054): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][720,1520] new=[0,0][720,1520] result=0x7 surface={true 3583346688} changed=true
I/OpenGLRenderer( 4054): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer( 4054): Swap behavior 2
D/mali_winsys( 4054): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/OpenGLRenderer( 4054): eglCreateWindowSurface = 0xec07aca0, 0xd5958808
D/ViewRootImpl@e295047[MainActivity]( 4054): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager( 4054): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@4a801ba[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager( 4054): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/SurfaceView( 4054): onWindowVisibilityChanged(8) false io.flutter.view.FlutterView{9a0a9e3 VFE...... ........ 0,0-720,1436} of ViewRootImpl@e295047[MainActivity]
W/libEGL  ( 4054): EGLNativeWindowType 0xd5958808 disconnect failed
D/OpenGLRenderer( 4054): eglDestroySurface = 0xec07aca0, 0xd5958800
D/ViewRootImpl@e295047[MainActivity]( 4054): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][720,1520] new=[0,0][720,1520] result=0x5 surface={false 0} changed=false
D/SurfaceView( 4054): onWindowVisibilityChanged(4) false io.flutter.view.FlutterView{9a0a9e3 VFE...... ........ 0,0-720,1436} of ViewRootImpl@e295047[MainActivity]
D/ViewRootImpl@e295047[MainActivity]( 4054): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][720,1520] new=[0,0][720,1520] result=0x1 surface={false 0} changed=false
D/ViewRootImpl@e295047[MainActivity]( 4054): stopped(false) old=true
D/SurfaceView( 4054): windowStopped(false) false io.flutter.view.FlutterView{9a0a9e3 VFE...... ........ 0,0-720,1436} of ViewRootImpl@e295047[MainActivity]
D/ViewRootImpl@e295047[MainActivity]( 4054): stopped(false) old=false
D/SurfaceView( 4054): onWindowVisibilityChanged(0) true io.flutter.view.FlutterView{9a0a9e3 VFE...... ........ 0,0-720,1436} of ViewRootImpl@e295047[MainActivity]
D/ViewRootImpl@e295047[MainActivity]( 4054): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][720,1520] new=[0,0][720,1520] result=0x7 surface={true 3583348736} changed=true
D/mali_winsys( 4054): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/OpenGLRenderer( 4054): eglCreateWindowSurface = 0xec07aca0, 0xd5959008
```

Comment: When you change things when debugging and if you unplugged, the changes will not apply because those change are not built into apk. What you have to do is just run the app again and unplug and test or try `flutter run --release`

Comment: When I try flutter run --release   I got this message:
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Do not run this command from the root of your git clone of Flutter.

Comment: As the error message says you are not inside your flutter project root directory.

Comment: it still shows these messages, what I do? thanks for help

Comment: I updated the packages and gradle also today, but it still shows these messages

Comment: Note that I did flutter run --release but it still shows these messages.